# How to change port java.exe

Tags: java, port

```
java.exe TCP    843     0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0     Listening       Java(TM) Platform SE 6 U31  Java(TM) Platform SE binary 6.0.310.5   Sun Microsystems
```

I want change port 843 to other port.

Comment: There is no chance we can help you unless you tell us what Java application you are running.

Answer (score 2):

It is not Java itself what is listening on port 843. It must be some running Java application. That is why you have to reconfigure the application itself to make it run on other port, there is no general solution to your question.

See https://superuser.com/questions/212296/find-out-what-program-runs-in-the-java-exe-process

In the post above there is a manual how to find out which application is running as java.exe. Then you can track it down and destroy it or reconfigure it.